# CSS - Redimensionar fondo blanco de imagen

Tags: html, css

Estoy tratando de realizar el desafío "Build a Tribute Page" en la web de [Free Code Camp.](https://www.freecodecamp.org/challenges/build-a-tribute-page)

Sin embargo me encuentro con um problema en css. Yo quiero que el tamaño del recuadro blanco de una imagen sea menor a lo que veo. Pero no sé exactamente que modificar. Por otro lado tampoco sé exactamente como googlear el término que necesito. La imagen de lo que tengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código donde está la imagen:

```
  .image {
    display: block;
    padding: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
```

El HTML de la imagen es el siguiente:

```
<div class="image">
  <img 
    src="http://www.subeimagenes.com/img/los-simuladores-tlf-723143.jpg"
    alt="panflet">
  <div class="captiontext">
The four assosiates: Mario Santos, Emilio Ravenna, Pablo Lampone, Gabriel Medina    
  </div>
</div>
```

[Código de todo el proyecto en Code Pen](https://codepen.io/jchemile/pen/jwRaWd)

Gracias!

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el html para tener más información?

Comment: Editado el código y agregado enlace al proyecto en codepen

Comment: Podrias darle un width fijo a la clase image y modificar el display del contenedor principal para que no se te alinee a la izquierda

Comment: Problema resuelto. Gracias!

Comment: Puedes anexar la solución como una respuesta, por favor?